# Constructor is never used

Tags: java, android

Have some questions.

I have a parent class

```
abstract class Tetramino{}
```

and some child classes that extends parent with a default constructors listed explicitly

```
class LineHorizontal extends Tetramino
{
  LineHorizontal() { // do some}
}

class LineVertical extends Tetramino
{
  LineVertical () {// do some}
}
```

And I have a generator class which generate child classes

```
class MinoGenerator
{
    private static final String TAG = "MinoGenerator";

    private static final Class[] types = {LineHorizontal.class,     LineVertical.class, Square.class,
        L0.class, L90.class, L180.class, L270.class, LR0.class, LR90.class, LR180.class,
        LR270.class, T0.class, T90.class, T180.class, T270.class, Z0.class,
        Z180.class, RZ0.class, RZ180.class};

    static Tetramino next()
    {
        try{
           int type = (int) (Math.random() * types.length);
           return (Tetramino) types[type].newInstance();
       } catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating new tetramino");
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

When I want create new one, I call next().
Then a newInstance() function, calls consturtors implicit and return a random one.
But android studio mark a constuctors with warning "Constructor neve used", how I can fix it?
Thanks for reply.

Comment: show code for new instance.

Comment: Note: don't use non-empty arrays for static final variables: they are inescapably mutable. Use `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(LineHorizontal.class, LineVertical.class, ...))`. The other benefit of this is that you can declare it as `List<Class<? extends Tetramino>>`, and not have to cast on the `return (Tetramino) types[type].newInstance();` line.

Comment: newInstance() is a build in java function, which create objects by RTTI info.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` hover your class

Like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class MyClass{

    public MyClass(){}
}
```

This works on IntelliJ IDEA and i think that can work also on Android Studio

Comment: this solution seams like putting the power switch off so that a faulty bulb is not caught. Though we do somethings sometime like this but then we must have a very strong reason to do so...

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this, assuming you're using [Jack](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html), is to use lambda expressions:

```
private static final List<Supplier<? extends Tetramino>> types =
    Collections.unmodifiableList(
        Arrays.asList(
            LineHorizontal::new,  // or () -> new LineHorizontal()
            LineVertical::new,
            // etc, for other types
            ));
```

Then, in your `next()` method:

```
return types[type].get();
```

Note that this is actually using the constructor of the class, so you won't have unused warnings any more. And it's more type safe than reflection.